# How to fire an action in a React component when a key is pressed?

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks, keycode

I need to know how to make a certain action/function to be called when a certain key is pressed inside a React component.

How can I make this cutomizable for different keys.

Note: This question is asked by myself to provide an answer (share with the community) for people wondering in case some function like this was not shared before.

Also if you have any suggestion or comments on my answer please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do these making a reusable function like below that has a map of all or most of the keys:

```
export const useKeyboardBehaviour = (key, effect, event) => {


const keyCodeMap = {
    backspace: 8,
    tab: 9,
    enter: 13,
    shift: 16,
    ctrl: 17,
    alt: 18,
    pause: 19,
    capsLock: 20,
    escape: 27,
    pageUp: 33,
    space: 32,
    pageDown: 34,
    end: 35,
    home: 36,
    arrowLeft: 37,
    arrowUp: 38,
    arrowRight: 39,
    arrowDown: 40,
    printScreen: 44,
    insert: 45,
    delete: 46,
    0: 48,
    1: 49,
    2: 50,
    3: 51,
    4: 52,
    5: 53,
    6: 54,
    7: 55,
    8: 56,
    9: 57,
    a: 65,
    b: 66,
    c: 67,
    d: 68,
    e: 69,
    f: 70,
    g: 71,
    h: 72,
    i: 73,
    j: 74,
    k: 75,
    l: 76,
    m: 77,
    n: 78,
    o: 79,
    p: 80,
    q: 81,
    r: 82,
    s: 83,
    t: 84,
    u: 85,
    v: 86,
    w: 87,
    x: 88,
    y: 89,
    z: 90,
    numpad0: 96,
    numpad1: 97,
    numpad2: 98,
    numpad3: 99,
    numpad4: 100,
    numpad5: 101,
    numpad6: 102,
    numpad7: 103,
    numpad8: 104,
    numpad9: 105,
    multiply: 106,
    add: 107,
    subtract: 109,
    decimalPoint: 110,
    divide: 111,
    f1: 112,
    f2: 113,
    f3: 114,
    f4: 115,
    f5: 116,
    f6: 117,
    f7: 118,
    f8: 119,
    f9: 120,
    f10: 121,
    f11: 122,
    f12: 123,
    numLock: 144,
    scrollLock: 145,
    semiColon: 186,
    equalSign: 187,
    comma: 188,
    dash: 189,
    period: 190,
    forwardSlash: 191,
    openBracket: 219,
    backSlash: 220,
    closeBracket: 221,
    singleQuote: 222,
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const action = (e) => {
      if (e.keyCode === keyCodeMap[key]) effect();
    };
    document.addEventListener(event || 'keydown', action);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener(event || 'keydown', action);
    };


   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
};
```

Then you can call it like this inside your component:

```
useKeyboardBehaviour('escape', () => console.log('Esc key was pressed'));
```